# TeamCity launch application after build

Tags: .net, teamcity

As the last step of my build I'd like to deploy my WPF application. I need to copy it to stage and launch it. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should mess building and deploying; what you can do, however is to setup a powershell script or an application that will run on your staging server and pool the TeamCity API for latest build. When available, download the installer, install the application and launch it.

There are commercial solutions that do that already. If your company can afford it, try [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/automated-deployments/teamcity-deployment); we are using it successfully but with TFS not TeamCity.

Comment: I ended up using BuildMaster as they provide a free license